# Mac HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-emulator, osx-yosemite

I have been running to the following error with Latest Android Studio.

> emulator: The memory needed by this VM exceeds the driver limit. HAX
>   is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode

I am using Mac Pro with OS 10.1.xx

I have also executed required intel drivers and confirming the installation by running the following command in Terminal Console.

```
kextstat | grep intel
```

But I am still getting the same error.

Please help.

Comment: Amount of memory when you installed HAXM and amount of memory of your emulator device? If you set 1 gb ram when you installed HAXM and your device has 1536 for example, haxm cant works.

Comment: @Dahnark thank you. I have 4 GB in total and I was reluctant to give more than 1 GB as I thought 1 GB is enough to run this simulator. Nevertheless I was wrong. After reinstalling intel HAX and giving 2 GB RAM has fixed my problem.

Comment: Say me when you try if it works to put it like answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amount of memory when you installed HAXM and amount of memory of your emulator device? If you set 1 gb ram when you installed HAXM and your device has 1536 for example, haxm cant works.

Comment: That's not really an answer.  How do you increase the HAXM memory or reduce the device memory?

Comment: @FlorianF reinstalling HAXM. Indeed, the setup specifies that you should reinstall to change the amount of ram that HAXM is going to use.

Comment: Thanks.  My problem was that my HAXM was bundled with Android Studio so I couldn't restart the installation.  But in the meantime, I managed to download HAXM alone and reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

Try reducing the Ram of your Virtual Device to the one on HAXM and it should work!!! To do that go to Tool->andriod->Avd and then select your device and click on pen . go to Advance and locate the Ram option and reduce it from there